# Caching polygons on google map

Tags: google-maps, polygon

have successfully rendered polygons in google map. I want to save them for offline use.
Is there a way to cache polygons on google map and use them later ?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut
Google provides the kml-Format for such glorious things.